# jQuery animate zoom requires me to click body?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to allow for zooming of a specific element

Like so:

```
jQuery('#center-of-attention').animate({"zoom": "+=5%"}, 5);
```

It all works fine, but in order for it to zoom, I need to have clicked on the body at least once it seems? I'm not sure why. I've trying running the animate just by it's self but it still doesn't work.

EDIT:

This is my full code,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var currentZoom = 100;
    jQuery(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){

        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
            zoom('in');
        } else {
            zoom('out');
        }

    });
   function zoom(zoomState) {
        if(zoomState == 'in') {
            if(currentZoom < 150) {
                jQuery('#center-of-attention').animate({"zoom": "+=5%"}, 5);
                currentZoom += 5;
            }   
        } else {
            if(currentZoom > 100) {
                jQuery('#center-of-attention').animate({"zoom": "-=5%"}, 5);
                currentZoom -= 5;
            }       
        }
    } 

});
```

The mousewheel listener runs fine (on chrome, haven't tested it elsewhere yet) and is definitely not the problem (I tested it with console.log on chrome)

Comment: When do you want the animation to occur? Please show the code that doesn't work, including the function within which that line appears.

Comment: I've updated it @nnnnnn

Comment: you need not click on the body but the mouse must be hovering over the body

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to do it as soon the page is loaded, then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#center-of-attention").animate({"zoom": "+=5%"}, 5);})
```

And just btw, 5 is very small duration (that's 5 ms), to see any animation, use 500 (that's 0,5 s), for example :)

Example (with a bit longer animation and more zoom (50%), to let you see the effect):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){$("#center-of-attention").animate({"zoom": "+=50%"}, 500);})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="center-of-attention">some text there</div>
```

## Edit

There is another problem, as I can see. It does work for me,  but maybe you try adding this to your document ready...

```
$( "document.body" ).focus()
```

Comment: Hi @nicael I am running 5 seconds because it runs on mousewheel. don't think I was clear enough unfortunately. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Matthew - it's not 5 *seconds*, it is 5 *milliseconds*.

Answer (score 0):

Update based on comment:

You need not click on the `body` but your mouse must be on the page. Only then the mousewheel will event will be triggered.

On page page set the focus on that particular element. `$("body").focus();` to get event trigger.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dizoxu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**

you must run it inside the dom ready event handler

```
$(function() {
  jQuery('#center-of-attention').animate({"zoom": "+=5%"}, 5);
});
```

Change the animation time you're passing to the animate function. `5` is too small value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a conflict with jQuery UIs "Draggable" function.
This required me to select the element before it became 'visible' in the DOM